# How to outsource this file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add social buttons with the following code, but I can outsource it in a js file because the buttons stop working:
However no problem with of course the css code.
the first part is javascript
the second one is css
and the last one is html

when all the scripts are in the html page, it works fine.

Could you help ?:

```js
var wSize = "width=600,height=460",
    loc = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href),
    title = "share",
    // Sharer URLs
    fb = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=", // 0. Facebook
    tw = "https://twitter.com/share?url=", // Twitter (separate function)
    gp = "https://plus.google.com/share?url=", // 1. Google+
    tb = "http://www.tumblr.com/share?v=3&u=", // 2. Tumblr
    rd = "http://reddit.com/submit?url=", // 3. Reddit
    li = "http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=", // 4. LinkedIn
    su = "http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=", // 5. StumbleUpon
    digg = "http://www.diggo.com/submit?url=", // 6. Digg
    pt = "http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=", // 7. Pinterest
    // Twitter custom texts
    text = $(this).attr('data-title'),
    hashtag = "hashtags=" + $(this).attr('data-tags'),
    via = "via=frenchspanish",
    // URLs array
    url = [fb, gp, tb, rd, li, su, digg, pt];
function share(i) {
    "use strict";
    window.open(url[i] + loc, title, wSize);
}
function twitter() {
    "use strict";
    window.open(tw + loc + "&" + text + "&" + hashtag + "&" + via, title, wSize);
}
```

```css
ShareWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40%;
    background-color:white;
    z-index:20;
    left: -50px;
}
.Share {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20%
}
.ShareIcon {
    margin-left: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.Share a{
    display:block;
}
.socialLinks ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
.socialLinks ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
}


a.social-button {
    
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 4px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
}

    a.social-button:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a.social-button.twitter-button {
        background-color: #4099ff;
    }

        /*a.social-button.twitter-button:before {
            content: 't';
        }*/

        a.social-button.twitter-button:hover {
            background-color: #303030;
        }

    a.social-button.facebook-button {
        background-color: #3b5998;
    }

     
        a.social-button.facebook-button:hover {
            background-color: #303030;
        }

    a.social-button.googleplus-button {
        background-color: #dd4b39;
    }


        a.social-button.googleplus-button:hover {
            background-color: #303030;
        }

    a.social-button.pinterest-button {
        background-color: #c8232c;
    }

      
        a.social-button.pinterest-button:hover {
            background-color: #303030;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" ShareWrapper">
            
          <div class="Share">
            
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ShareIcon" title="Share"><i class="fa fa-share social-button"></i></a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="twitter()" data-title="Title" data-tags="Tags" title="Share on Twitter" class="social-button twitter-button"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Share on Facebook" onclick="share(0)" class="social-button facebook-button"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Share on Google plus" onclick="share(1)" class="social-button googleplus-button"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="share(7)" class="social-button pinterest-button" title="Share on Pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="share(3)" class="social-button reddit-button" title="Share on Reddit">
                  <i class="fa fa-reddit-alien"></i>
              </a>

              <!-- StumbleUpon-->
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="share(5)" class="social-button stumbleupon-button" title="Share on Stumbleupon">
                  <i class="fa fa-stumbleupon"></i>
              </a>

              <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="share(4)" class="social-button facebook-button" title="Share on LinkedIn">
                  <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
              </a>
         </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: A) It's called "sourcing". B) Check your JavaScript console for import errors.

Comment: Place your `script` tag that references the external file just before the close of the `body` tag (`</body>`) so that by the time the script runs, all of the HTML will have been parsed into memory and the code can find the buttons.

Comment: And, make sure you have jQuery referenced before your own custom `script`.